# How to set the max value in the heatmap properly setData?

Tags: javascript, arrays, heatmap

I have some data saved and it is huge, 100.000 plus points saved in the database. In this format:

```
 database_data = [
                   { x: 100, y: 100, value: 1},
                   { x: 200, y: 100, value: 1},
                   { x: 120, y: 320, value: 1},
                   ...
                 ]
```

I am giving the value of 1 for each point as you can see above. I would like to use:

```
heatmap.setData({
    max: max_value,
    data: database_data
});
```

To plot the data on the screen. How can I calculate the max_value of the heatmap? Because I wanna have the information been displayed on the screen where the most red color is the points where we have more frequently in the database and the less red color would be the point where we have only once in the database. But as we know, (x:100, y:100) and x:120, y: 120) will have some intersection between them, and that would also need to be consider, just like the normal heat map.

In other words, I want to know how to automatically calculate the value for "max" in the heatmap using setData function!
Here below it is a function that is working fine, but it takes too much time:

```
var body = document.body;
var bodyStyle = getComputedStyle(body);
var hmEl = document.querySelector(".heatmap-wrapper");



hmEl.style.width = bodyStyle.width;
hmEl.style.height = bodyStyle.height;
hmEl.style.background = "#3e1852";
hmEl.style.zIndex = "1000";

var hm = document.querySelector(".heatmap");

var heatmap = h337.create({
    container: hm,
    radius: 40,
});

var dbh_x = <?php echo $dbh_x;?>; //LIKE THIS->["100", "200", "300","400", "420", "500", "600", "600"];
var dbh_y = <?php echo $dbh_y;?>;//LIKE THIS->["100", "200", "300","400", "420", "500", "600", "600"];

for ( var i =0; i< dbh_x.length; i++){
    heatmap.addData({
        x: dbh_x[i],
        y: dbh_y[i],
    }); 
};
```

Because of the loading time, I was trying to use setData instead:

```
var body = document.body;
var bodyStyle = getComputedStyle(body);
var hmEl = document.querySelector(".heatmap-wrapper");



hmEl.style.width = bodyStyle.width;
hmEl.style.height = bodyStyle.height;
hmEl.style.background = "#3e1852";
hmEl.style.zIndex = "1000";

var hm = document.querySelector(".heatmap");

var heatmap = h337.create({
    container: hm,
    radius: 40,
});

heatmap.setData({//This function will show the data kind a fast for 100000+points
    max: 10, //This is the problem
    data: [{ x: 891, y: 50, value: 1},{ x: 891, y: 50, value: 1},...]

});
```

Appreciate your guys time!

Comment: Not sure I understand. In order to have the max value, you either need to iterate the array of points or maintain some `max` variable during the building of your heatmap

Comment: I have a huge array where stores the position of the mouse for ever 0.1 seconds in the case of users. And of course having the same point if kind a rare right? So I am giving the value: 1 for all points and I would like to basically add them, just like `heatmap.addData{x: pageX, y: pageY,})` Because that function will make the colors less red if I add more points to another position. And that is what I want, I want the strongest point to be the most red one. Got it?

Comment: Or could you just tell me how to add an array of data in the heatmap.js, without using loops

Comment: Whenever you update a value of a point, you can also check if this value is higher than the current `max`. If so, you update `max` - and then you can just access it when you need it

Comment: All the values I am uploading are 1's only, so how can I implement that in the code?

Comment: If you tell me how do other companies bring the saved data during months and show such data with heatmap, is basically the same I am looking for

Comment: @HygisonBrandao `h337.create` won't work?

Comment: The heatmap is working fine, I am using that as well before. But the problem is to load a huge amount of points over 10000 points. If I use a for loop to do that, and user addData, it will give me exactly what I want, but it takes too much time. So I was trying to use setData() instead, but that function only does not correct the redness of the points, because there is a max value which I am having problems to calculate. Got it?

Comment: I have edited my question, I believe it is easier to understand now =)